# Equivalent of LINQ in Java 8

Tags: java, .net, linq, lambda

Is there an equivalent to `LINQ` in java 8?
Did `lambda` expression fill this role?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Java's [Stream API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) is the closest thing to .NET's LINQ, in the sense that it allows you to query/manipulate collections in a functional style.

Answer (score 8):

No, lambda expressions are not LINQ equivalent. LINQ (at least parts of it) uses lamba expressions for some functionality. But they're fundamentally different things.

1. Lambda expressions: expressions used as anonymous functions
2. LINQ: Language integrated query.

Comment: Can you provide some more explanation as to why they are different? Their syntax looks very similar.